# JPA @OneToMany relationship table does not have enough columns

Tags: java, jpa, relationship, jpa-2.0

In my app, I have the following @OneToMany relationship:

```
@Entity
public class ReservedLessons extends ReservedSessions implements Serializable {

    @OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST})
    private List<Lesson> reservedLessons;

}

@Entity
public class Lesson extends Sessions implements Serializable { ... }
```

I expected to see the table `reservedlessons_lesson` with 2 columns `ReservedLessons_ID` and `reservedLessons_ID`. However, when I ran the app, the table only had 1 column `ReservedLessons_ID`.

In my app, I also have several other `@OneToMany` relationships and all of them have a table with 2 columns. I'd be very grateful if you could show me what I have done wrong.

Comment: Why are expecting to see the table reservedlessons_lessons with 2 columns? Have you configured your Persistence in order to create the db tables? Otherwise I can't understand your sentence. Can you also show the definition of ReservedSessions Entity?

Comment: @perissf: I expected to see a table with 2 columns because with `@OneToMany` relationship, JPA will automatically create that table to record the relationship.

Comment: You mean join table ? because you haven't defined it to use one.

Comment: @DataNucleus: I have other `@OneToMany` relationships and I also didn't specify anything but they had their own table. In fact, this one also has a table but it seems to lack 1 column.

Comment: Just with OneToMany annotation and no JoinTable annotation should NOT give a join table, as per the JPA spec. You don't say which is your JPA implementation

Comment: @DataNucleus a table should always be created. Otherwise, please tell me how the JPA can record which `Lesson` entity is in the relationship with which `ReservedLessons` entity.

Comment: @DataNucleus: if what you mean is that a FK will be created in the `Lesson` entity, what you said only occurs if the relationship is bidirectional or if it is a `@ManyToOne` relationship specified in the `Lesson` entity. In this case, it is a unidirectional `@OneToMany` relationship specified in the One side. You can actually do a simple test to see that you don't need `@JoinTable` annotation. In fact, I don't have any `@JoinTable` annotations anywhere. How do you explain the existence of the `reservedlessons_lesson` table?

Comment: @DataNucleus: I am using `EclipseLink (JPA 2.0)`. Actually, I did go to section 2.10.5.1 of [Persistence 2.0 Final spec](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/) and I saw they mentioned the *default* mapping with JoinTable. Am I looking at the wrong part of the spec? Can you show me where they mentioned what you said?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I was careless when I was naming my `ReservedLessons` entity and its `reservedLessons` property. Since the 2 column names are actually the same in MySQL, my join table lacks a column it should have. After I change my `ReservedLessons` to `ReservedLesson`, my join table now has 2 columns `ReservedLesson_ID` and `reservedLessons_ID` as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You should use @ManyToOne at other side of your mapping to make it bidirectional ([example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JPA/OneToManyBidirectionalMapping.htm))

Comment: I am not intending to create a bidirectional relationship.